# which component should i use to create chat gui in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, chat, fxml

for typing the text i am using TextArea because its allow multiple  text.

And for showing the CHAT SEND message and CHAT RECEIVED message
 currently i am using ListView But Problem is It show string only in sinle line.

```
   @FXML
    private ListView listView;
    ObservableList<String> listViewData= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    //on Action calling this
        listViewData.add(textArea.getText());
        textArea.clear();
```

[image]

which componet shuold i use to show text in multiple lines??

Comment: You can use custom `ListView` to change the way to want the cell to appear. For some details, go through http://fxexperience.com/2012/05/listview-custom-cell-factories-and-context-menus/

Comment: which component should i use within Custom ListView??

Comment: What about using styled, colorful Texts or Labels in VBox/HBox.